# 'No action was found on the controller that matches the request.' in webforms app trying to make WebAPI call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I know there's lots of questions asked/answered about this, so I guess I'm missing something. I just can't see the problem here. Any help is appreciated.

ajax call:

```
    $('#btnGetShipMethods').click(function () {
        var basketguid = 'abcd';
        var data = {
            BasketGuid: basketguid
        };
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/Checkout/GetShipMethods",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('Success: ' + msg);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Failed " + error.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

controller:

```
public class CheckoutController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Checkout/GetShipMethods")]
    public string GetShipMethods(string BasketGuid) {
        var basket = DbBasket.GetBasket(BasketGuid);

        return BasketGuid;
    }
}
```

global.asax Application_Start

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When making a `POST` request and sending a body you are essentially creating an `object` with a set amount of properties. In this case you're sending an `object` with a property but you're accepting only the property in `.Net` (not the `object`).

To fix this you need to create a model with `BasketGuid` property and accept it in your endpoint. Something like the following.

```
...
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Checkout/GetShipMethods")]    
public string GetShipMethods([FromBody]Basket basket) {
...
```

The `Basket` class would look something like this

```
public class Basket
{
    public string BasketGuid {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that. The call is then successful but the parameter BasketGuid is null.

Comment: Try creating a Model with the property BasketGuid and accept it as a parameter.

Comment: @BrandonSpilove I've updated my answer. Check it out and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Nope, still get the error about No action was found on the controller... The only thing that seems to work is if I append a querystring on the ajax url like this: "/api/Checkout/GetShipMethods?BasketGuid=abcd". But this seems odd since I am trying to do a POST. Why can't I just pass a simple string?

Comment: Try what i suggested + [FromBody]

Comment: I appended the example

Comment: Nope, same error. [FromBody] works when it is a string and then the controller finds the method, but it was always passed as null.